# Removing borders from a table in an array environment

Tags: tables, mathjax

I have the following table:

```
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 2 & a & b \\ \hline 3 & c & d \\ \hline  \end{array}
```

which gives me:

[image: table before]

However, I want something like this *using the same array environment* (as I'm using the code for a Moodle webpage and Moodle doesn't support a tabular environment):

[image: result]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `\begin{array} {r|r|r} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline 2 & a & b \\ 3 & c & d \\  \end{array}`

Comment: @gernot Thank you for your answer. Is there a way I can align each element in the table to its cell's center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to remove vertical lines  end `\hline`s which you not needed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array} {c|c|c}
1 & 2 & 3   \\ 
    \hline 
2 & a & b   \\ 
3 & c & d   \\  
\end{array}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If I replace some elements in the table with a longer string of text, the elements look decentralized. How I align each element in its cell's center?

Comment: @Jana With the `c` specifier as in Zarko's solution, the entries are centered. In your question, you use `r`, which right-aligns the entries. I'm referring to the string `c|c|c` vs. `r|r|r`.

Comment: @Jana, now the cells contents are centered, also at longer text in some cell. Only column become wider.

Comment: @gernot, now I see, that you provide similar solution in comment, a minute before my answer ...